# Error: ORA-00911 invalid character

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle, ora-00911

When trying to run this query on cx_Oracle in python

```
Insert into orange.cp4_freeze_tasks (
SELECT distinct cust_id, 'C' 
  FROM (SELECT f.cust_id, cust_site, debt_invoiced + debt_no_invoiced deuda,
     DECODE (d.manual_level, 0, cp_level, manual_level) nivel,
     (SELECT nvl(freeze_limit,9999999999)
        FROM orange.cp4_level_config
       WHERE site_id = cust_site
         AND cplevel =
                  DECODE (d.manual_level,0, cp_level,manual_level)) freeze_limit
   FROM orange.cp4_freezed_customers f, orange.cp4_debt_status d
  WHERE f.cust_id = d.cust_id) c
 WHERE deuda <= freeze_limit / 2 and not exists (Select 1 from orange.cp4_freeze_tasks 
where cust_id = c.cust_id and task_status = 'C'));commit;
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Already tried the solution from other questions: Deleting the last semicolon.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: post the full stack trace, please

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, except ending with commit within your sql statement.  Can you remove the commit and commit otherwise from python, like, connection.commit();?  Otherwise, you would wrap the statements in an anonymous pl/sql block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to guess it's this that's causing the problem:

```
where cust_id = c.cust_id and task_status = 'C'));commit;
```

You've got two SQL statements in the one query. Remove the `;commit;`. Your  insert statement should now work. Change your python and add this after you run the insert:

```
connection.commit()
```

Obviously change `connection` to fit the actual variable name you use.

Comment: That did the trick! For a moment I thought it was not working but the query needed its time. Thank you!